# Applying scene changes through service call does not block until changes are applied

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a follow up to question: https://answers.ros.org/question/352589/planner-not-planning-around-obstacles-in-scene/

According to [the tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/planning_scene_ros_api/planning_scene_ros_api_tutorial.html#interlude-synchronous-vs-asynchronous-updates). using the service call should block until the scene changes are applied.
However, I found that after the `/apply_planning_scene` service returns, querying the planning scene with

```
planning_scene_monitor::LockedPlanningSceneRO scene(my_planning_scene_monitor);
```

does not give me a scene with the scene changes applied.  A slight delay is required before the returned scene contains the changes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352721/applying-scene-changes-through-service-call-does-not-block-until-changes-are-applied/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The service applies the scene to the `PlanningScene` instance maintained by the `move_group` node.
There is no way for it to wait until your, or any other `PlanningSceneMonitor`, that might listen to the monitored planning scene topic processed the update.
If you want a deterministic way to retrieve the updated scene, you have to request it via the `get_planning_scene` service from the `move_group` node.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2020-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-05-19**:
Is this the correct way of retrieving the updated scene and converting it into a `PlanningScenePtr` to be used for planning?

```
moveit_msgs::GetPlanningScene get_planning_scene_call;
get_planning_scene_call.request.components.components = get_planning_scene_call.request.components.WORLD_OBJECT_GEOMETRY;
get_planning_scene_service_client.call(get_planning_scene_call);
planning_scene_monitor::LockedPlanningSceneRO scene_snapshot(monitor);
planning_scene::PlanningScenePtr current_scene(scene_snapshot->diff(get_planning_scene_call.response.scene));
```

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2020-05-20**:
The idea looks ok. When requesting `WORLD_OBJECT_GEOMETRY`, quite often you might want to have `ROBOT_STATE_ATTACHED_OBJECTS` and possibly `ALLOWED_COLLISION_MATRIX`.
Looks like you know what you're doing though, so that's mostly a comment for other readers in the future.
Also I'm not sure what happens when your local scene monitor receives the same updates again a moment later via the monitored topic. It should not be a problem though.
Alternatively you can also wait for the change to appear in your local monitor on its own (will happen soon after your request), but depending on the configured rates your proposed approach will be much faster.

That being said, I'm personally not a fan of local `PlanningSceneMonitor`s to begin with.
Either you maintain *your own* scene entirely using a PlanningSceneMonitor and do not care about `move_group` at all, or you write `MoveGroupCapability`s and run your workload in `move_group` directly.
Mixing these approaches is always difficult

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-05-20**:
@v4hn Yeah I'm starting to feel my approach of maintaining a local `PlanningSceneMonitor` is fundamentally flawed.  Where can I find more information regarding writing `MoveGroupCapability` so I can use the existing `move_group` stuff?  Is it the [MoveGroup C++ Interface](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/move_group_interface/move_group_interface_tutorial.html) you're talking about?